# Capturing code generated by Qemu in a file

Tags: linux, qemu

In qemu, when we are giving instructions it gets converted to the machine code for the particular architecture. I would like to write this code to a file. For that I think in cpu-exec.c the generated code is obtained (it is returned for execution). How will i copy it to a file?

```
 /qemu-0.14.0/cpu-exec.c
```

Answer (score 0):

find cpu_gen_code() @ translate-all.c:57, 
-to->
@ line104:  log_disas(tb->tc_ptr, *gen_code_size_ptr);
try to hack it.